# MS Access “Update or CancelUpdate” error using Find dialog

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

We have an MS Access 2007 database with a simple form displaying table data. We use the Find dialog (click the binoculars on the Home ribbon) to locate records we want. This can cause an error under specific circumstances.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Open the form.
2. Open the find dialog.
3. Edit some field within the record.
   The record is now in update mode
   (you'll see the pencil in row's
   "gutter" area).
4. Without saving the record, click on
   the ALREADY open Find dialog.
5. Search for a record that can't be
   found.
6. Click on the form again. The record
   is still in edit mode (i.e. the
   pencil still shows). Attempt a save
   or edit some other field.
7. This message box will display
   "Update or CancelUpdate without
   AddNew or Edit." You can click OK or
   Help buttons.

Clicking the Help button shows:

> You tried to call Update or CancelUpdate or attempted to update a Field
>      in a recordset without first calling AddNew or Edit. (Error 3020)
>
> On a Microsoft Access database engine database, you called the Update or
>      CancelUpdate method but did not use the AddNew or Edit method before writing
>      data to a record.
>
> On an ODBCDirect database, this error occurs when you attempt to write data
>      to a record without first calling AddNew or Edit.

We’ve reproduced this in a new database where there is no VBA code. So the problem is solely within MS Access, and you should be able to reproduce it easily.

If you save the record before doing the find, the problem doesn’t happen. Unfortunately, we have users doing a find while the record is still in edit mode.

We’ve tried setting up form-level, data-field-level, and Access application level events and error handling. Nothing can detect or catch this situation. There is no way within VBA to detect if the Find dialog is active.

Does anyone have any ideas for preventing the error or a way to save the record before the find occurs? Our best thought right now is to create an AutoHotkey or AutoIt script that waits for the Find dialog to have focus. We’ll then send a Ctrl+S to save the current record to force a save.

Comment: Is customizing the ribbon to change to find function an option for you (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/customize-the-ribbon-HA010211415.aspx) ?

Comment: Ctrl-S does not save the record. It saves the design of the current UI object (in this case, the form you're editing).

Comment: As @Remou suggests, I'd replace the default FIND shortcut with one that does a save before opening it, or write my own find code. In general, I would say relying on the UI's find function indicates an underdeveloped application user interface.

Comment: My boss uses the binoculars and he frequently has trouble with errors like this or similar. I'm quite sure the problem is not in my code either (and you pretty much proved that). I've been wishing there was a way to trap for his using of the binoculars but that isn't possible either, as far as I know. Customizing the UI is probably your best bet, IMO.

Comment: I can't duplicate this on my copy of MS Access 2007. Are you patched up to date?

Comment: @CodeSlave - Yes, we have all the latest patches. I'm not sure why you can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hack, work-around we came up with was to write an [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) script which can watch for when the Find dialog gains focus and save the record if it has changed.

We didn't want to distribute the script separately from the database, so the the script was added to a database table as a Blob.  The database's AutoExec macro runs some VBA code that pulls the script out of the Blob table and starts the script.

When the script detects that the Find dialog has focus, the script runs a VBA macro in the database. The macro checks to see if the current record is dirty. If dirty, the macro forces a save. Also, the AutoIt script is stopped when the database is closed.

This is all pretty awkward, but it works.

Comment: That's horrific. I would design my own FIND and eliminate the binoculars from the toolbar/ribbon before I'd ever consider anything as awful as that.

Comment: I agree using the AutoIt script is a hack. But we decided this was the quickest way to get the database functional for our internal users. If we were delivering a customer product, we would try a more polished approach. We think recreating the functionality of the Find dialog would take a lot of effort because the dialog has some interesting features (like determining which form field has focus).

Comment: Determining what field has the focus is completely trivial, i.e., `Screen.ActiveControl`, which you'd call before opening your custom Find form.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you've found a bug that was introduced in MS-Access 2007. However, I have not been able to duplicate it on my copy. I presume we're both up to date on our patches, so perhaps there is something more subtle happening.

If you're wanting to force the record to be saved, use one of the the following - not a CTRL-S

- `if me.dirty then Me.Dirty = false ''(n.b. often the preferred method)`
- `Docmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`
- `DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acRecordsMenu, acSaveRecord, , acMenuVer70 ''(n.b. deprecated)`

The problem as I understand it, is that if they edit the form after the "find" is already open and then do the "find" the get the error.

I'd try one of two things:

1. Find a way to close the built in find form, and do so whenever you make the current record dirty (On Dirty)
2. Add your own "find" button to the form (not opening the built in find form), and hide the one on the ribbon.

Comment: DoMenuItem has been deprecated since at least 2000. DoCmd.RunCommand is the alternative, but for saving records, checking `If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False` is often recommended.

Comment: @Remou - 1) It seems to still work 2) I pesumed that 2007 wizard would generate better code than the version I had available to me at the time (2003); hence my "or whaterver line" (just tried it... macros... ugh) . 3) I had no idea that `Me.Dirty = False` has the side effect of saving the record as well (it certainly is not listed in the help files). 4) Point taken, I've learned something new, and will use it in future.

Comment: I gave in to the temptation, sorry, but if you would like to edit your answer, I will reverse the down vote.

Comment: I was shocked when I found out about Me.Dirty = False, since it seemed like .Dirty should so obviously be read-only. But I thankfully learned it shortly after it was introduced, so haven't been having to use other methods over that long period of time.

Answer (score 1):

@CodeSlave's answer suggests a possibility to me:

Instead of simply removing the binoculars from the toolbar/ribbon, instead change what the binoculars do. That is, have it call code that saves the current record if it's dirty and then launches the FIND dialog.

Now, there'd need to be some code to check that a form was open, and that it had a recordsource (testing the .Dirty property errors if there's no recordsource), and that a field has the focus, but all of those things are doable. Likely many of them (except the last) would be taken care of by showing the toolbar/ribbon only when the form is loaded, or by editing the default toolbar/ribbon when the form opens.

But this would be much less crazy than using an out-of-process solution, and your users wouldn't know any difference.

Comment: I think that the issue is, that the FIND dialog is already open before the edit. So inserting the save when the dialog is opened won't solve the problem.

Comment: Ok, so you lock the controls on the form, or just set it to be uneditable until the Find dialog is closed. Oops. Dunno how you find out it's been closed...so, I guess you're left with rolling your own find dialog to replace the built-in Access one (I've never really liked it that much, myself).